# Display only 8 lines of text in a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this unique situation in front of me where i want create a function to show only 8 lines of text whatsoever. The website is responsive. Here is what i have tried:

```
var fontSize = $target.css("font-size").match(/\d/g).join(""),
lineWidth = $target.width(),
totalLetters = $target.text().length,
lettersPerLine = (totalLetters * fontSize) / lineWidth,
numOfLines = Math.round(totalLetters/lettersPerLine);
```

The Problem:

1. The font i am using is not monospaced which means that not all the letters are of equal width.
2. I dont want to pass WordsPerLine as a parameter to the function i will write, i want it to calculate this
3. I am not sure/cannot find out what the browser does to wrap text to new lines. For example, if the `<p>` width is 600px then it is obvious that 900 words wont fit in one line.. the browser will wrap the text to new lines.. but what does the browser do to achieve this, does it insert a new line character `\n` ?
4. The above piece of code does not work for me and i don't no why...if you have a clue (which i am sure you smart people definitely know what i am doing wrong), please shed some light.
   All suggestions are deeply appreciated.

Comment: Would a CSS solution be acceptable?

Comment: Why not set the container to have a max-height equal to 8 lines of text, and overflow set to hidden...  http://jsfiddle.net/R8wAb/

Comment: @JohnKugelman Sure sir, i am aware that we can clip off text are certain point and create excerpt with CSS but i wanted a more cross browser solution.. but please share what you have got, thanks for the help

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks! that gave me an idea.. i also wanted to show "Read more" link if this was the case but i think i can do it based on the height!! Oh my god, i did not think of it.. thanks

Comment: @LuckySoni What is the expected behavior when there's less than 8 words?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c63aZ/ Here is a simple fiddle to detect an overflow and add a read more div.

Answer (score 3):

After wanting to know this a few times, a soultion I came up with is pre-calculating the height and width the characters by having them rendered, cache this and produce a lookup function.

The following works as long as `body > span` will be rendered. The parameters are optional, defaulting to the style of `body > span` and the first `255` chars of the font.

```
function charSizes(numChars, cssFont) {
    var span = document.createElement('span'),
        text = document.createTextNode(''),
        uia, i, j;
    span.appendChild(text);
    if (cssFont) span.style.font = cssFont;
    span.style.padding = span.style.margin = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(span);
    numChars = (numChars || 255);
    uia = new Uint32Array(numChars * 2);
    for (j = i = 0; i < numChars; j = 2 * ++i) {
        text.data = String.fromCharCode(i);
        uia[j] = span.offsetWidth;
        uia[j + 1] = span.offsetHeight;
    }
    // free memory
    document.body.removeChild(span);
    span = text = numChars = cssFont = null;
    // output lookup function
    return function (c) {
        var i = c.charCodeAt(0) * 2;
        return {
            width: uia[i],
            height: uia[i + 1]
        };
    };
}

var arial12 = charSizes(0xFF, '12px Arial');
```

Now you can look up characters easily

```
arial12('a'); // {width: 7, height: 15}
arial12('-'); // {width: 5, height: 15}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy css solution would be to set the container's height to `8em` and set overflow to `hidden`.

In practice I have found this to be inaccurate.  Here is a jQuery solution (assume I have a `div` with the id of `bozo`):

### JavaScript

```
function getFontHeight(className) {
    $testdiv = $('<div stlye="white-space:nowrap;">jgpqAZ</div>');
    if (className) $testdiv.addClass(className);
    $('body').append($testdiv);
    var height = $testdiv.innerHeight();
    $testdiv.remove();
    return height;
}

$('#bozo').height(getFontHeight() * 8);
```

### CSS

```
#bozo {
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ufNA/1/)