# Marquee text - Getting length of text in pixels that is outside of screen boundaries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport

I am trying to get the length of a news feed that scrolls from one side to the other on a page. I need to calculate the width of the text in pixels to determine when to re-position at the start.

I have wrapped the news feed text inside a div container. The text has the CSS rule `overflow: visible;` and `white-space: nowrap;` set.

But when i try to grab the text's length in pixels: I only get the maximum width of my viewport.

I use the following jQuery to grab the length: `$(".scroll-text").width();`

That only goes up to the maximum viewport size of my browser.

**Is there any way to determine the text's length in pixels that includes text off the viewport/screen?**

**EDIT:** Here is my markup: http://pastebin.com/kTuMfZtd

---

*Message for you that may flag this post as duplicate:*

It is not a duplicate. There is no question that regards to pixel length outside of screen boundaries.

Comment: can you share your HTML markup, so that we can see how the marquee has been implemented?

Comment: @Shiva Added markup link.

Answer (score 1):

It took me forever to find, but perhaps you want something like in my answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281490/display-only-8-lines-of-text-in-a-container/18282031#18282031).

Using this code, you can find the width of text and from that, calculate the width your string would be.

```
function charSizes(numChars, cssFont) {
    var span = document.createElement('span'),
        text = document.createTextNode(''),
        uia, i, j;
    span.appendChild(text);
    if (cssFont) span.style.font = cssFont;
    span.style.padding = span.style.margin = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(span);
    numChars = (numChars || 255);
    uia = new Uint32Array(numChars * 2);
    for (j = i = 0; i < numChars; j = 2 * ++i) {
        text.data = String.fromCharCode(i);
        uia[j] = span.offsetWidth;
        uia[j + 1] = span.offsetHeight;
    }
    // free memory
    document.body.removeChild(span);
    span = text = numChars = cssFont = null;
    // output lookup function
    return function (c) {
        var i = c.charCodeAt(0) * 2;
        return {
            width: uia[i],
            height: uia[i + 1]
        };
    };
}

var defaultFont = charSizes(0xFF); // match the style of the text in your marquee
                                   // using the second parameter if necessary
```

Now

```
var str = 'foobar', i, len = 0;
for (i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    len += defaultFont(str[i]).width;
}
len; // 36 pixels on this page
```

---

If we had more information about your markup, you might be able to measure the *#text* nodes in your *DOM* directly.

Comment: I get the following error when i run this script: http://puu.sh/7T1eO.png

But errors aside: It seems to work. I have yet to test it for my marquee text. Stand by.

Comment: Sorry. Can't seem to get it working. I get a `NaN` value back when i try to use it.

Comment: @DJZorrow the `0xFF` basically means "the first 256 characters". Are you using non-ASCII/ANSI characters (they would be outside this range)?

Comment: I do. I use ÆØÅ (3 ending characters in the Norwegian alphabet) as additional characters. How would i go about adding those?

Comment: I'm not sure where your _NaN_ is coming from. They should be included (`198`, `216`, `197`). `JSON.stringify('ÆØÅ'.split('').map(defaultFont)); // "[{"width":13,"height":16},{"width":11,"height":16},{"width":9,"height":16}]"`

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the element with you favorite browser:

[image: 563px width in this case]

Comment: When i do this: It actually shows the correct width it should get. But for some reason: jQuery cuts of at the screen width.

Comment: Please tell us what css is applied on `body` and `html`, your html opening tag (first line of you template) and if you are using meta tags regarding the viewport.

Comment: You have a syntax error in line 162: Please remove `});`. Next: you have to refernce the id, not the class, try `$("#scroll-text").width();`. Share your results please.